# Why is my input form canvas graph disappearing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, input, html5-canvas

In the apple counter I have built, it should work as follows:

1. Enter a number
2. Click the button
3. print the canvas as informed by the input entered in step 1.

However, it seems like when I click to submit, either the screen goes blank, or the expected output flashes on the screen and then disappears to a blank screen.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Here is the relevant meat of the code:

### html:

```
<body>
<form>
    How many apples? <input id="apples"></input><br/>
        <button onclick="draw()">Count!</button>
</form>
    <canvas id="tutorial" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


var draw=function(){

      //footer
      ctx.font="16px futura"
      ctx.fillText("Apples",10,140);


      //create and scale image of apple
      var appleImg = new Image();
      appleImg.src ="http://cdn.oxwordsblog.wpfuel.co.uk/wpcms/wp-content/uploads/apple-e1382039006457.jpg";
      ctx.save();
      ctx.scale(0.06,0.06);


      //use input value to print apples
var appleIn = parseInt(document.getElementById("apples").value,10);
              for(var i=0;i<appleIn;i++)
      {
      ctx.drawImage(appleImg,0,i*525);
      }

}
```

---

here is a link to my code as well:
http://www.codecademy.com/curiousgeorge/codebits/3FPdqV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Button Tag doubles as a clickable element and a submit button. You need to provide what kind of button you want it to be:

```
<button type="button" onclick="draw();">Count!</button>
```

So add **type="button"**.